# We know $A_5$ as a non-CI-group. Now, is $A_5$ a BI-group?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, character-theory

*‎We call a group satisfying the following property for all $\nu \in cd(G)$ (Irreducible character degrees of $G$) a **BI-group** (Babai Invariant group)*

> Let $G$ be a finite group‎, ‎let $\Gamma=Cay(G,S)$ be a Cayley graph‎, ‎$\nu\in cd(G)$ (an irreducible character degree of $G$). Then $M_\nu^S=\{\sum_{s\in S}\chi_i(s) \;\vert\; \chi_i(1)=\nu, \chi_i \in Irr(G)\}$ is an *invariant* of $\Gamma$. (Thus‎, $Cay(G,S)\cong Cay(G,T)$ implies that $M_\nu^S=M_\nu^T$).

Now, I have two questions:

1) **Is $A_5$ a BI-group?**

2) **Which non-abelian groups of order less than $100$ are BI-group?**

> We do it by **GAP** [1], but it is very time consuming and infeasible.

[1] *A. Abdollahi and M. Zallaghi*, MR 3395696 [**Character Sums for Cayley Graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2014.967398), *Comm. Algebra* **43** (2015), no. 12, 5159--5167.

Comment: Maybe by computation with MAGMA and by transforming the memory domain to time domain in programming, we can study all cases. The question seems interesting.